# Setting Template FreeMarker for mapList inside a List

Tags: freemarker

i have data-Model like this,

```
contentList = [ 
       { "Product" : "Book", "Qty" : 10  },
       { "Product" : "Pencil", "Qty" : 10  }
]
```

and i want to display it in template like this

```
     PRODUCT                      QUANTITY
   1.  Book                            10
   2.  Pencil                          10
```

when i use this code,

```
<#list contentList as content>
   <#assign i = 1>
      <#list content?keys as key>                     
         ${key}: ${content[key]}  
       <#assign i = i + 1>
   </#list> 
</#list>
```

the result is like this.

```
1.  Book
2.  10
1.  Pencil
2.  10
```

i use this link to test it, https://try.freemarker.apache.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

already figure it out by myself. For data-Model I use this

```
contentMap = {
   "Book" : 10,
   "Pencil" : 10
}
```

and in my template i use this

```
<#list contentMap as key, value>
      ${key} : ${value}
</#list>
```